# Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am importing a file from BOX. I have used box sdk V2. It's importing successfully but as it imports the screen has to navigate on a next controller. I am having crash on this

```
NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryOptionView"
                                                      owner:nil
                                                    options:nil];
```

and this is the error

> Assertion failure in void
>   _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(),
>   /SourceCache/UIFoundation_Sim/UIFoundation-229/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1516
>   2013-11-22 08:04:10.083 PunchList[1019:6a2b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Only run on the main thread!'

Comment: +1 Interestingly I'm also using Box SDK v2, and having a similar problem when pushing a view controller. I think it's something to do with the way Box is wrapping stuff in an auto release pool? because that's where it breaks for me (in BoxAPIOperation). I "fixed" the problem by wrapping the VC push in performSelector:withObject:delay: with 0 delay (basically postponing till end of run loop). :/

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, because people like we are sometimes scared that How to a sk question, or lack of time (excuses), we are not asking the question.. thanks for asking question, mine has solved .

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, the exception reason gives the problem away; you should run this code on the main thread. Try enclosing the view creation and nib loading using `dispatch_sync` or `dispatch_async` and passing the main queue using `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Comment: Thanks alot for you support.

Comment: @Leo I have the same problem and saw the reason -- but do you know: why would it run it NOT in the main thread? I'm getting it when I execute a modal segue, oddly only on the physical device, not in the simulator.

Comment: @TimErickson How are you executing the segue?

Comment: @Leo your question has solve my answer, thank you very very very much for helping me. Now I am running all my jobs in main queue...